# How to efficiently initialize a std::variant data member in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics, std-variant

Consider the following class template, that can hold either a value of type `T` or an instance of some `ErrorInfo` class, using a `std::variant` data member:

```
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError
{
  private:
    std::variant<T, ErrorInfo> m_var;
};
```

How can I *efficiently* initialize the variant `T` alternative?

I can initialize it with a constructor like this:

```
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError
{
  public:
    explicit ValueOrError(const T& val) 
        : m_var{val} 
    {
    }

    …
};
```

But what syntax/coding technique can I use to enable *move semantics* optimization during initialization?

If I define a constructor taking a `T&&`, should I `std::move` or `std::forward` the parameter into the `m_var`?

```
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError
{
  public:
    // Efficient initialization with move semantics 
    explicit ValueOrError(T&& val)
        : m_var{ /* ?? */ } 
    {
    }

    …
};
```

---

### Note on interactions with ErrorInfo constructor overload

The `ValueOrError` template should also have a constructor overload that takes an `ErrorInfo` and initializes the variant member accordingly:

```
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError
{
  public:
    // Initialize with error code instead of T
    explicit ValueOrError(const ErrorInfo& error) 
        : m_var{error} 
    {
    }

    …
};
```

It’s important that the generic `T` constructor overload interacts properly with the specific `ErrorInfo` overload.

`ErrorInfo` is a tiny class that wraps an error code (e.g. a simple integer), and can be constructed from such error code:

```
class ErrorInfo
{
  public:

    explicit ErrorInfo(int errorCode) 
        : m_errorCode{errorCode} 
    {
    }

    int ErrorCode() const 
    {
        return m_errorCode;
    }

    // … other convenient methods 
    // (e.g. get an error message, etc.)

  private:
    int m_errorCode;
};
```

Comment: Just move it, surely: https://wandbox.org/permlink/507Z0zyT50sF7Mk5

Comment: Also, idiomatic might be to pass `val` by value and (also) move at the call site.

Comment: It's worth noting that the constructor `ValueOrError(T&& val)` is not a template, hence, `std::forward` is not the tool of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C++20 version using [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```cpp
#include <concepts> // std::constructible_from

template <class T>
class ValueOrError {
public:
    explicit ValueOrError(const ErrorInfo& error) : m_var{error} {}

    template<class... Args>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
    explicit ValueOrError(Args&&... val) :
         m_var(std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(val)...)
    {}

private:
    std::variant<T, ErrorInfo> m_var;
};
```

A C++17 version, also using perfect forwarding, could look like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_constructible_v, std::enable_if_t

template <class T>
class ValueOrError {
public:
    explicit ValueOrError(const ErrorInfo& error) : m_var{error} {}

    template<class... Args,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>, int> = 0>
    explicit ValueOrError(Args&&... val)
        : m_var(std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(val)...) {}

private:
    std::variant<T, ErrorInfo> m_var;
};
```

Example usages:

```cpp
class foo { // A non default constructible needing 3 constructor args
public:
    foo(double X, double Y, double Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
private:
    double x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    ValueOrError<foo> voe1(1., 2., 3.); // supply all three arguments

    // use the string constructor taking a `const char*`:   
    ValueOrError<std::string> voe2("Hello");

    std::string y = "world";
    // use the string constructor taking two iterators:
    ValueOrError<std::string> voe3(y.begin(), y.end());
}
```

Comment: That's surprisingly straightforward. I've never fully grokked the proper use of `std::enable_if` for SFINAE purposes, nice to know C++20 is rewarding my laziness. :-)

Comment: On the subject of things I've never fully grokked, would there be any advantage to replacing `: m_var(T(std::forward<Args>(val)...))` with `: m_var(std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(val)...)` following [Marek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953882/364696) (adding the `...` unpacking)? Not sure if that gets any benefits like avoiding a move construction or avoiding ambiguity from argument types or the like.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, absolutely. I used the wrong constructor at first but corrected it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Could you please provide a solution that also works with **C++17** (in addition to the C++20 concept-based solution)? I tried removing the `requires` (concept) line and adding this kind of SFINAE parameter to the `explicit ValueOrError(Args&&... val)` constructor: `std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>>* = nullptr`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Mr.C64 I added a C++17 version.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this this way in C++17 (using "perfect forwarding" + SFINAE):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    explicit ValueOrError(U&& val, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U>>* = nullptr)
    {
       m_var.template emplace<T>(std::forward<U>(val));
    }

private:
    std::variant<T, ErrorInfo> m_var = ErrorInfo{0};
};
```

Question is how this interact with constructors were error should be used?

Or initialization list version:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ValueOrError {
public:
    template <typename U>
    explicit ValueOrError(U&& val, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, U>>* = nullptr)
        : m_var { std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<U>(val) }
    {
    }

private:
    std::variant<T, ErrorInfo> m_var;
};
```

I have doubts if version with multiple arguments to construct `T` should be implemented. It is possible, but IMO will make code harder to read.

https://godbolt.org/z/scxacMn3W

Comment: Why is that better than just moving it, @Marek (see my link).

Comment: this is "perfect forwarding". Google what is it.

Comment: Thanks MarekR. This is what I was thinking about.

Comment: Minor note: Should `std::in_place_type_t<T> {}` just be `std::in_place_type<T>` (no `_t`, not `{}` to construct)? Seems like the type is only needed for declaring the function, and the helper without `_t` can be used without explicit construction (and seems to be the recommended way, hell if I know).

Comment: @MarekR: Thanks. I tried the second code snippet and it works. It would be interesting to see an implementation that includes also the multiple argument constructor option, still using C++17.